# When do we create memory for ivars in Singleton example by Apple?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen the Apple's example of Singleton and couple of other examples.
People say that it is too strict!

But the point is ..even if it is too strict, I want to understand it.
I dont understand that when we call allocWithZone on super, What happens ?

Memory will be created according to super's instance size.

What if our Singleton has ivars ?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32

I also dont understand that, Why does allocWithZone return the object with a retain call when retain itself is returning the object as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a method is called in Obj-C it is passed an object reference via the hidden parameter `self`. For an instance method `self` refers to the object the method was invoked on, for a class method `self` refers to the the class object (of type `Class`) the method was invoked on. Calls to `super` implicitly pass on `self`.

Therefore in Apple's example code the call `[super allocWithZone:NULL]` calls the super implementation of `allocWithZone` passing the current value of `self`, which is `MyGizmoClass`'s class object as it is a static method. The implementation of `allocWithZone` can determine the required memory size from the passed `Class` object – the details of how are private.

As you've correctly spotted, the call to `retain` in `allocWithZone` is pointless but harmless.